# Python barchart overlapping vertical bars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, weather

I have two graphs that share the same x-axis. They are both time series with 2880 times (4 months with hourly data). I have an array with the values of precipitation for every hour (2880). I want to overlay this data via a vertical bar chart over the first graph, so that the bars width is equivalent to 1 hr and centered over the corresponding hour.

My issue is that the widths of the bars are too wide and overlap with each other.  I have tried changing the width option to width=1/24 in the plot with no success (bars don't appear at all). Here is a snippet of the code where I do not set the width at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(datetime.datetime(2010,1,01,0), datetime.datetime(2010,5,01,0),datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).astype(datetime.datetime)
stn_temp = np.random.rand(2880)
model_temp = stn_temp-0.2
stn_rh = np.random.randint(0,100,2880)
model_rh = stn_rh -1
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)
ax1.plot(t,stn_temp,'r',linewidth=0.3)
ax1.plot(t,model_temp,'k',linewidth=0.3)
minor_ticks_temp = np.arange(min(stn_temp),max(stn_temp),1)
ax1.set_yticks(minor_ticks_temp, minor=True)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax1.legend(loc=0)
ax1.set_ylabel('2 m Temperature ($^\circ$C)')
ax1 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.bar(t,prec,alpha=0.7,color='g')
ax1.set_ylabel('Accumulated \n Precipitation (mm)')
ax2.plot(t,stn_RH,'b',linewidth=0.3)
ax2.plot(t,rh,'k',linewidth=0.3)
ax2.set_ylim([0,100.5])
ax2.set_ylabel('Relative Humidity (%)')
fig.tight_layout()
```

The widths of the bars should be a lot smaller, only the width of an hour. This image is a zoomed in version to show the bar width issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that illustrates your problem using fake data? Right now no one can run your code except you because the data are not available.

Comment: It's not clear what "I have tried changing the width option" means. The width of the bars is determined by the `width` argument. So bars should be 1 day wide. To make them 1 hour wide, use `width=1./24`. I'm not sure if the ticks are located correctly but one can only find out with a  [mcve].

Comment: If bar's don't appear it is because one hour in the graph is less than a pixel.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You're indeed correct and that was the issue after all.  Thanks!